# error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-c++, pycharm

there I am stuck in the above error while installing "pgeocode" library of python in pycharm.
I already have Microsoft visual c++.
I don't have enough data now to download the visual studio again. So please help me

Comment: I already have Microsoft visual c++ 14

Answer (score 0):

The `Visual C++ 140` is not a component of Visual Studio. Ignore the name, visit the site https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145 and follow the details.

Comment: To elaborate, a lot of Windows applications use the same code. Instead of it being duplicated across all applications on your computer, taking up a lot of space both on disk and in memory, there are some core DLLs that can be shared. However, since compiled code is a fragile thing, you have to use the correct version of these DLLs. the "140" version is used by applications compiled by Visual Studio 2015. I guess that's how pgeocode was compiled, and you're just missing the DLLs it requires.

Comment: it is not 140, it is 14.0.23026.0 version